# what is the com.mysql.jdbc.integration.jboss.ExtendedMysqlExceptionSorter equalant in mariadb

Tags: jboss, datasource, mariadb

Can any one please tell me what the mariadb counterparts to the following **`classes :`**

```
com.mysql.jdbc.integration.jboss.ExtendedMysqlExceptionSorter
com.mysql.jdbc.integration.jboss.MysqlValidConnectionChecker
```

I need to change from connectorj to maria db in jboss 6.1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: MariaDB is (supposedly) a drop-in replacement for MySQL. It should be compatible with your existing code, so no changes should be necessary. Get more info at [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/)

Comment: thanks for responding. but the problem is that I will have to remove the connectorj jar and add the maraidb jar instead. so the classes wont be available.